# React native app : Not authorized to use location services

Tags: react-native, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I'm currently working on a project that uses the geolocation service of my phone. 
I currently have a prolem with this service, it says that geolocation is not authorized.

I've tried to look on the internet and a few people had the same problem but I didn't manage to fix it...

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { coordinate } = this.state;

    this.requestCameraPermission();

    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
      position => {
        const { routeCoordinates, distanceTravelled } = this.state;
        const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;

        const newCoordinate = {
          latitude,
          longitude
        };
        console.log({ newCoordinate });

        coordinate.timing(newCoordinate).start();

        this.setState({
          latitude,
          longitude,
          routeCoordinates: routeCoordinates.concat([newCoordinate]),
          distanceTravelled:
            distanceTravelled + this.calcDistance(newCoordinate),
          prevLatLng: newCoordinate
        });
      },
      error => console.log(error),
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 20000,
        maximumAge: 1000,
        distanceFilter: 10
      }
    );
  }
```

Instead of appearing on my current spot, i'm in San Fransisco (which is the default location on maps). 
The function navigator.geolocation.watchPosition gets the error : 
 "code": "E_LOCATION_UNAUTHORIZED",
  "message": "Not authorized to use location services",
  "watchId": 1,

My phone is a Samsung S9 and the location service is enabled... So I'm really curious about the problem I have right now.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your answer, I managed to fix my problem, apparently expo wasn't allowed to use my location for some reason, so I just forced it with :

```
  Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';

await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
```

Alternative method if ***requestPermissionsAsync();*** is unable to work.

Comment: This answer is just 2 days old but seems you didn't checked the docs, as both of the things have been changed.  Permissions are being added to their respective packages and also in Location we have now seperate permissions for foreGround location and backGround location. Please check.  BTW i am here to find some answer for this problem.  For me it is device specific also because on snack.expo.io and on one of my devices, it works fine but on another device it shows error and also blocks the location access without even prompting me.

Comment: I'm using expo 36 if I remember correctly

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Expo client** on your mobile then please make sure you have enabled the location permission.

If you already given the permission, then check your **AndroidManifest.xml** for
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>` for these locations.

Comment: When testing this, do I add it in the `debug/AndroidManifest.xml` or `main/AndroidManifest.xml`? Does it need to be in both?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the case when `iOS` worked fine without asking explicitly in the `.ts` code for any permissions. However, `Android` showed that warning `Not authorized to use location services`.
The `Permissions` have slightly different syntax now, here is an example with `Location`.

```
if (Platform.OS !== "web") {
  const { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
  
  if (status !== "granted") {
    Alert.alert(
      "Insufficient permissions!",
      "Sorry, we need location permissions to make this work!",
      [{ text: "Okay" }]
    );
    return;
  }
}
```

(in general) Don't mess up anything in the **AndroidManifest.xml**, like `<uses-permission android:name=...`, because whatever `Expo` needs will generate automatically there. That's the case for `Location`, [citing official docs](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/permissions/#bare-workflow-1):

*"Some Expo and React Native modules include permissions by default. If you use expo-location, for example, both the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION are implied and added to your app's permissions automatically."*

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `react native` you may need to add following in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file,

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake on my part, but don't forget to `await` the method `requestForegroundPermissionsAsync`. Only then use `Location`'s methods

```
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

const result = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
```